# Example s.t. $\phi^* \circ\mathbb{V}(\mathfrak{b})\subsetneq \mathbb{V} (\mathfrak{b}^c)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi:A\to B$ be a $\mathtt{CRng}$ morphism. It can be shown that $\overline{\phi^* \circ \mathbb{V}(\mathfrak{b})}=\mathbb{V}(\mathfrak{b}^c)$ 
where $\phi^*: \mathtt{Spec}(B)\to \mathtt{Spec}(A)$ is induced by the inverse of $\phi$ on prime ideals of $B$. What I'm looking for is an example of $\phi \in \mathtt{CRng}(A,B)$ and prime ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ such that $\phi^* \circ\mathbb{V}(\mathfrak{b})\subsetneq \mathbb{V} (\mathfrak{b}^c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of examples. If $\mathfrak{b} \subseteq B$ is a maximal ideal, but $\mathfrak{b}^c \subseteq A$ is not maximal (take for example the inclusion of an integral domain into its field of fractions), then $V(\mathfrak{b})$ is a single point, but $V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$ is not. Hence $\phi^*$ doesn't map $V(\mathfrak{b})$ onto $V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$.